# Lua string from file

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to make a system which backs up and restores points for a gameserver, so it can safely restart without loosing anything. 
I have made a script to do just this and the actual backing up part works fine, but the restore part does not.

This is the script that runs if 'Backup(read)' is used (Backup(write) works perfectly as it is designed to do):

```
if (source and read) then
  System.LogAlways("[System] Restoring serverdata from file 'backup.CHK'");
    for line in source:lines() do
      Backup = {};
      Backup.Date = (Date or line:match("File Last Modified: (.-)"));
      Backup.Time = (Time or line:match("time: (.-)"));
      US = tonumber((US or line:match("us: (.-)")));
      NK = tonumber((NK or line:match("nk: (.-)")));    
      local params = {class = "Player"; 
                      position = {x = 1, y = 1, z = -1000};
                      Respawn = { bRespawn = 0; nTimer =0; bUnique = 1; }; 
                      bUsable = 0; 
                      orientation = {0, 90, 135}; 
                      name = "BackupEntity"; };
      local ent = System.SpawnEntity(params);
      g_gameRules.game:SetTeam(1, ent.id);
      g_gameRules.game:SetSynchedEntityValue(playerId, 100, (NK/3));
      g_gameRules.game:SetTeam(2, ent.id);
      g_gameRules.game:SetSynchedEntityValue(playerId, 100, (US/3));
      System.RemoveEntity(params);
    end
  source:close();
  return;
end
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong,and most sites that I have looked at don't help that much. The problem is that it's not reading any values from the file.

Any help will be appreciated :).

**Edit:**

The reason that we have to divide the score by 3 is because the server multiplies all scores by 3. If we were not to divide it by 3, then the score will always be 3 times larger on each restore.
Example contents of the backup.CHK file:

```
The server is dependent on this file, and writes to it every hour. Please do not edit.

    File Last Modified: 11/07/2013
    This file was generated by the servers' autobackup system.

--------------------------

    time: 22:51
    us: 453445
    nk: 454567
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant that this was the code for `Backup(read)` (where read is a properly set variable that is truth-y. Can you post a sample of your backup file contents and what you expect loading the file to do exactly? That code doesn't look likely to be doing anything like what I would expect you to want.

Comment: Specifically, you never use the `Backup` table after assigning to it. You create a new `Backup` table for each line and then fill it in with defaults if specific values are not found on that line. `US` and `NK` are modified globally when they are read from the file.

Comment: See the edited question for an example of the file contents. The system needs to get the time and date of when the backup file was written, along with the score of the US and NK teams. It should then give the score to the player that we just spawned in the server temporarily in order to restore the teams' scores.

Comment: Does the backup file contain multiple entries for any of those fields or just one line for any given piece of information?

Comment: It just contains one line for each piece of information. For me, there is no need to have multiple backup files since this is a very busy gameserver and it backs up this way every hour.

Comment: The use of `(.-)` in your pattern looks suspicious. What's the reason for using lazy match?

Comment: The secondary programmer working on the server modification originally wrote the code, since he 100% knows Lua and I'm still learning. Changing to (%d) or (%s) does not make any difference.

Comment: `(.-)` matches the shortest possible. Maybe you're getting back an empty string because of it? Try `(.*)` or `(.+)`

Comment: Can you also be more exact on what you mean by "*...it's not reading any values from the file*"? What makes you say it's not reading?

Comment: @greatwolf: It's not reading any values from the file. For example, it's not reading time or date for a start, and not us or nk:

[System] Restoring serverdata from file 'backup.CHK'
[Warning] [Lua Error] scripts/system/utils.lua:41: attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'NK' (a nil value)
    > ServerBackup, (scripts/system/utils.lua: 41)
    > OnClientConnect, (scripts/gamerules/instantaction.lua: 462)
    > (null) (scripts/gamerules/teaminstantaction.lua: 517)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas of what might be causing the problem:

Use of `(.-)` lazy matching which matches the shortest pattern possible -- this can include an empty string. Usually, you want to make the pattern as specific as possible while still matching the required possible inputs. eg. It looks like `(%d+)` for `us` and `nk` is an appropriate fit.

The `for line in source:lines() do` reads *one* line at a time. That necessarily means not all the variables are going to be set inside the loop. Yet everything starting at `local params` and down uses those variables as if they were. It seems to me that section of code shouldn't even be in the loop.

Lastly, have you considered saving the Backup file as just another lua file? Doing so means you can let lua do the heavy lifting for you and you won't have to bother parsing it yourself. That also minimizes the risk for error.

Comment: I eventually settled on just saving it as an LUA script, it now works fine. Thanks for your help :).